# What are "custom prompts" in the Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: node.js, botframework

Since version 3.8, the Bot Framework now includes a handful of messages like this one:

> DialogAction.validatedPrompt() has been deprecated as of version 3.8. Consider using custom prompts instead.

I don't see any mention of this in the documentation.  What are "custom prompts," and where can I learn more about how they improve on the deprecated functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find an example on the Git Hub [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2741#issuecomment-300946349). The code provided in there can be found in the example is below:

```
// Create a recognizer for your LUIS model
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer('<model>');

// Create a custom prompt
var prompt = new builder.Prompt({ defaultRetryPrompt: "I'm sorry. I didn't recognize your search." })
    .onRecognize(function (context, callback) {
        // Call prompts recognizer
        recognizer.recognize(context, function (err, result) {
            // If the intent returned isn't the 'None' intent return it
            // as the prompts response.
            if (result && result.intent !== 'None') {
                callback(null, result.score, result);
            } else {
                callback(null, 0.0);
            }
        });
    });

// Add your prompt as a dialog to your bot
bot.dialog('myLuisPrompt', prompt);

// Add function for calling your prompt from anywhere
builder.Prompts.myLuisPrompt = function (session, prompt, options) {
    var args = options || {};
    args.prompt = prompt || options.prompt;
    session.beginDialog('myLuisPrompt', args);
}
// Then call it like a builtin prompt:

bot.dialog('foo', [
     function (session) {
          builder.Prompts.myLuisPrompt(session, "Please say something I recognize");
     },
     function (session, results) {
          switch (results.response.intent) {
               case 'Bar':
                    break;
          }
     }
]);
```

`